# Webi 4.1 BO variable not aggregating

Tags: business-objects, webi

I have created a measure variable:

```
= If IsNull([OBJECT 1]) And IsNull([OBJECT 2]) Then 0  ElseIf

Not(IsNull([OBJECT 2])) Then 

DaysBetween([DATE 1];[DATE 2]) 

Else 

DaysBetween([DATE 1];[DATE 3])
```

This works fine when the Unique Object is present but when I remove the unique ID I expect it aggregate but I get Multivalue. Please advise how best to correct this?

Thank you for your time in advance.

I have tried ForEach () to the Unique ID but still not getting what I need. I want a separate table with my Sum Count etc. as a dynamic Summary but getting Multivalue. This should be simple but it's creating a big headache !!!

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap your formula in a Sum() function...

[image]

That should do it...

[image]

Comment: Thanks Isaac for your reply and housekeeping !

This solution didn't work. I't probably due to the complexity of the underlying formulas within the table.

I guess my questions should be:

I have a table which calculates formula on a unique ID row by row basis. This creates an over all total for that row. I just need to be able to Sum that column (as one can do for the table) but in another table.

I've tried replicating the table then trying to hide the bulk of the data to just leave the Sum  (and count etc) Could you direct me to any training. I'm missing the concept here I think